# How do I repeat Scanf and Replace a Value?

Tags: c, stack, scanf

```
char *stack[13];
char INteger[100];
int top = -1;


int main () {
int current = 0;


    while (current < 2) {  

        Yfunc();
        printf("cell zero %s \n", stack[0]);
        printf("cell one %s \n", stack[1]);


void Yfunc() {

    printf("Please enter a string: \n");
    scanf("%s", INteger);
    push(INteger);

}
}

char *push(char input[]) {
     top++;
     stack[top] = input;
 }
```

Essentially the user is supposed to type in a string, let's say "Cow." This string is then pushed onto a stack (This works). However, when I push a second time the stack gets all messed up. I am assuming I cannot scanf(INteger) multiple times? If not, what is a fix to this?

Comment: Your push actually dont push, just set the pointer to the INteger string. So you dont copy the string actually.

Comment: You need to malloc space for a new string each time you get one from the user.  Otherwise, you're just re-using the same character array.

Comment: Robert Harvey, figured it was something like that. How would I get started. I am semi-familiar with malloc, but not sure how to do it regarding scanf and my code

Comment: You seem to be using nested functions, which means you're using a GCC extension feature and not one that I'd recommend you use.  Your code is also missing at least one close brace `}`.  Using the name `INteger` to represent a character string is a curious design choice — choosing good variable names is an important skill to learn.

Comment: Jon, it is part of larger code. I tried to simplify. It is called INTeger because the user types in "one", "two", etc. My apoligies, I forgot to change the variable name for the sake of SO

Answer (score 1):

So your `stack` is saving the memory address, but actually do not copy the content. A solution could be this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char stack[13][100];
char INteger[100];
int top = -1;

void push(char* input) {
   memcpy(stack[++top], input, 100);
}

void Yfunc() {
  printf("Please enter a string: \n");
  scanf("%s", INteger);
  push(INteger);
}

int main () {
  int current = 0;

  while (current++ <= 2) {  
        Yfunc();
        printf("cell zero %s \n", stack[0]);
        printf("cell one %s \n", stack[1]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As advice, how would you advise me solving a problem like this without always posting to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Well don't be ashamed to ask here anyway. Well It comes with experience. Try to use debuggers and think about what part is the cause. Narrow down the issue. And try different solutions. If one works and the others don't try to figure out why.